# Unusual x86 switch statement?

Tags: x86

I have come across the following x86 (Built with some version of Visual Studio AFAIK) switch statement:

```
0x1009E476  cmp edx, 0x3B
0x1009E479  jnz switch_statement

switch_statement:
0x1009E591  movzx ecx, byte [indirect_table+edx]
0x1009E598  jmp dword [table1+ecx*4]

indirect_table:
0x1009E7AB  db 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07
            db 0x07, 0x07, 0x06, 0x8B, 0xFF

table1:
0x1009E7B8  dd ptr code1
            dd ptr code2
            dd ptr code3
            dd ptr code4
            dd ptr code5
            dd ptr code6
            dd 0x00000000 
0x1009E7D4  dd 0x01060600, 0x06020606, 0x06060306, 0x06060606 ; Note: nothing directly references this data.
            dd 0x06040606, 0x06060606, 0x06060606, 0x06060606
            dd 0x06060606, 0x06060606, 0x06060606, 0x06060606
            dd 0x06060606, 0x06060606, 0x06060606, 0x06060606
            dd 0x06060606
```

No index in the `indirect_table` will end up referencing any of the 6 pointers in `table1`. Index 6 will dereference a null pointer, index 7 will dereference `0x01060600` and indexes `0x8B` and `0xFF` will end up dereferencing garbage. So everything will end up access violating.

So perhaps this is a compiler optimization, the data at table1 following the 6 code pointers and 1 null pointer looks like an indirect table, and coincidentally all indexes are suitable for this switch statement (0-6). While the binary has no references to this data, if `EBX` was known to be `0x29` or upwards, it would reference into this. The compiler may have decided `EBX` will not be `0`-`0x29` so moved the indirect table location backwards to line things up correctly. What then is the role of `cmp edx, 0x3B` in this?

**Is this a compiler code gen issue, a compiler optimization, or have I grossly misunderstood the code?**

If an optimization, any supporting reading material would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either there is a check somewhere before, or the compiler knows otherwise that `edx` is not less than 41 (0x29). 0x3B is probably handled by a single switch label, so the compiler added this check to avoid the double memory lookup (or maybe there's an actual `if` before `switch` in the source).

The table at 0x1009E7D4 is used to retrieve the jump table entry index - Visual C++ compiler always puts the indirect table after the jumps. 0x1009E7AB is likely a part of the previous switch's indirect table. And `8B FF` is `mov edi, edi`, used here for alignment.

This specific optimization (no subtraction for zero-indexing) seems to be pretty rare; I think I've only seen it in Windows DLLs which often use PGO and other tricks to achieve the last few percents of performance.

Comment: nicely spotted with the 'mov edi, edi' alignment! thanks for the good answer.